# Using expansion patch in devices that don't have external storage

Tags: android, sd-card, apk-expansion-files

I'm developing an Android app that has more than the 50mb apk limit. Therefore, I need to use expansion files. I've correctly implemented the solution for reading resources from the extension patch, but I have a problem with devices that do not have external storage.

When the device has external storage it works perfectly. The expansion file is saved in /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/main.1.package.com (example) but when the device don't have sdcard this solution doesn't work.

How can I use expansion patches with devices that don't have external sdcard?
Is there another folder where I can store the .obb file so that I can load my resources?

I'm using Google's Downloader implementation.

EDIT:

I know that the getExternalStorageDirectory does not necessarily means "external", it seems to be something with google Nexus devices...

Answer (score 0):

Google is quite clear on this:

> Google Play hosts the expansion files for your application and serves
>   them to the device at no cost to you. The expansion files are saved to
>   the device's shared storage location (the SD card or USB-mountable
>   partition; also known as the "external" storage) where your app can
>   access them.

If you want to save files to internal storage I think you have to make your own web service hosting your files and downloading them to internal storage. I think it would be waste of work as most phones comes with SD or build in SD card.